# Express 4 way to hook into app closing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing some regression test scripts for an express 4 app, and as the tests close down the server it complains that mongodb has not been closed down correctly, so is there a way to have some callback to notify you when the app is closing and close your stuff down there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try listening on the ['close' event](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_event_close) of the server and doing your additional cleanup there.

If you are currently using `app.listen()` you would have to change to something like:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.on('close', function() {
  // ...
});
server.listen(8000);
```

Comment: How do you go about doing this when the app is started via `myApp.listen()`, or is that bad practice and applications should be started explicitly via `http.createServer`

Comment: I've updated my answer. `app.listen()` does not return the server instance it creates for you, so you basically have to do it yourself.